# Unicode rectangles

Tags: code-golf, matrix, unicode

Given

- a matrix `a` of characters from `u=" ╶╺╵└┕╹┖┗╴─╼┘┴┶┚┸┺╸╾━┙┵┷┛┹┻╷┌┍│├┝╿┞┡┐┬┮┤┼┾┦╀╄┑┭┯┥┽┿┩╃╇╻┎┏╽┟┢┃┠┣┒┰┲┧╁╆┨╂╊┓┱┳┪╅╈┫╉╋"`
- the coordinates of a submatrix as `x`,`y`,`w`,`h` (left, top, width>1, height>1)
- a thickness `t` of 1 (as in `┌`) or 2 (as in `┏`)

render an inner border for the submatrix with the specified thickness, taking into account existing lines.

```
x=4;y=1;w=2;h=3;t=2;
a=[' ┌───┐',
   '┌┼┐  │',
   '│└┼──┘',
   '└─┘   ']

// output
r=[' ┌───┐',
   '┌┼┐ ┏┪',
   '│└┼─╂┨',
   '└─┘ ┗┛']
```

When overwriting a line fragment, the new thickness should be the greater of
the old thickness and `t`.

This isn't about input parsing or finding the Kolmogorov complexity of Unicode,
so you may assume `a`,`u`,`x`,`y`,`w`,`h`,`t` are available to you as variables.
Also, you may put the result in a variable `r` instead of returning or
outputting it, as long as `r` is of the same type as `a`.

If your language forces you to put code in functions (C, Java, Haskell, etc)
and your solution consists of a single function, you can omit the function
header and footer.

Larger test:

```
x=4;y=1;w=24;h=4;t=1;
a=['┏┱─────┐         ┌┐     ┎──┲━┓',
   '┠╂─────┘         ││     ┃  ┗━┛',
   '┃┃               ││     ┃     ',
   '┠╂──┲━━┓  ┏━━━━┓ ││    ┌╂┰┐   ',
   '┃┃  ┗━━┩  ┃    ┃ └╆━┓  └╂┸┘   ',
   '┃┃     │  ┃    ┃  ┃ ┃   ┃     ',
   '┗┹─────┘  ┗━━━━┛  ┗━┛   ╹     ']

// output
r=['┏┱─────┐         ┌┐     ┎──┲━┓',
   '┠╂──┬──┴─────────┼┼─────╂──╄━┛',
   '┃┃  │            ││     ┃  │  ',
   '┠╂──╆━━┓  ┏━━━━┓ ││    ┌╂┰┐│  ',
   '┃┃  ┗━━╃──╂────╂─┴╆━┱──┴╂┸┴┘  ',
   '┃┃     │  ┃    ┃  ┃ ┃   ┃     ',
   '┗┹─────┘  ┗━━━━┛  ┗━┛   ╹     ']
```

Comment: will the input always hold `0 <= x < x + w < width(a)` and `0 <= y < y + h < height(a)`?

Comment: @tsh yes, input will be valid

Comment: Bah, my default font is dodgy - it shows some of those characters with the wrong heaviness unless you zoom in a lot.

Comment: @Neil I'm sorry about that. One workaround is to paste the examples in an editor where you can choose the font.

Comment: About your bounty - it is impossible to award three 150-rep bounties. You have to double the rep count every time you start another bounty on the same question.

Comment: @MDXF Oh... I didn't think about that. Thanks. There must be ways around it though, e.g. start a bounty on a fake question.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 218 bytes

```
(a,x,y,w,h,t,u)=>a.map((l,j)=>l.map((c,i)=>u[(g=(a,b)=>a?g(a/3|0,b/3|0)*3+Math.max(a%3,b%3):b)(u.indexOf(c),t*((j==y||j==y+h-1)*((i>x&&i<x+w)*9+(i>=x&&i<x+w-1))+(i==x||i==x+w-1)*((j>y&&j<y+h)*3+(j>=y&&j<y+h-1)*27)))]))
```

`a` should be taken as array of array of char.

```js
f =

(a,x,y,w,h,t,u)=>a.map((l,j)=>l.map((c,i)=>u[(g=(a,b)=>a?g(a/3|0,b/3|0)*3+Math.max(a%3,b%3):b)(u.indexOf(c),t*((j==y||j==y+h-1)*((i>x&&i<x+w)*9+(i>=x&&i<x+w-1))+(i==x||i==x+w-1)*((j>y&&j<y+h)*3+(j>=y&&j<y+h-1)*27)))]))

x=4;y=1;w=24;h=4;t=1;
a=['┏┱─────┐         ┌┐     ┎──┲━┓',
   '┠╂─────┘         ││     ┃  ┗━┛',
   '┃┃               ││     ┃     ',
   '┠╂──┲━━┓  ┏━━━━┓ ││    ┌╂┰┐   ',
   '┃┃  ┗━━┩  ┃    ┃ └╆━┓  └╂┸┘   ',
   '┃┃     │  ┃    ┃  ┃ ┃   ┃     ',
   '┗┹─────┘  ┗━━━━┛  ┗━┛   ╹     '].map(x => [...x])
u=" ╶╺╵└┕╹┖┗╴─╼┘┴┶┚┸┺╸╾━┙┵┷┛┹┻╷┌┍│├┝╿┞┡┐┬┮┤┼┾┦╀╄┑┭┯┥┽┿┩╃╇╻┎┏╽┟┢┃┠┣┒┰┲┧╁╆┨╂╊┓┱┳┪╅╈┫╉╋";

output = f(a,x,y,w,h,t,u).map(x => x.join('')).join('\n');
document.write(`<pre lang="en" style="font-family: Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif;">${output}</pre>`)
```

Comment: as mentioned above, you are allowed to replace `(a,x,y,w,h,t,u)=>...` with `r=...`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>226</s> <s>201</s> 197 bytes

```python
n,m=x+w-1,y+h-1
r=[*map(list,a)]
R=range
for i in R(x,x+w):
 for j in R(y,y+h):A,B=j in(y,m),i in(x,n);r[j][i]=u[sum(3**o*max((i<n*A,y<j*B,x<i*A,j<m*B)[o]*t,u.index(a[j][i])//3**o%3)for o in R(4))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbUhpBEH3fr9iyKrU766pl4EnYB/kEXzc8UBUTloKFQijhTSH3i5J4JpiQ@91cjUkMxlz@5fwImdkFg@jU1E53T59zunun0qzly2FiUPemTMp9yp@U3wkQkvKAuEd0Kb8Ra5S/iG1C2fvEA6JPqOQ@5R9inbhPKOAPokco4CGlsm8Rt4kW8ZB4RPmXeEw8IzrEB@IT8ZJQtIrhNaWSuETcIT4Sn4lXxG9CQXYo25RXKQ@JDWKTUsWfEM@JNvGUeEHcJXaJPeIN5TrlFeItZYvyBrFFfCG@Eu8oL1NeI95TXqe8OWUYDS@ZanrzqVXvbDKVV05NOUbO8y2to3Frx3fHHK2ouc7Q3Bjd70Wz2LJcQ8UtXZ2qYpJke4xE3baGZlt/uhFB74igHcWPrUmQTjxNL65Fl6MTN0feKPafRreiYbtxQxPao5rU3jlS1Id@JnrSIwVEJP24v5MNRGJj8CFH@7Q2utEbOjm2sVri3RubmSaSBzFR1lB/sRis1OxSrmJrw80JMQjdkteYXp2Zd5vT@Zl5o@r5zlhC1ljyqrnw4rJxoVw1AzMIzSW74SqEWDBMHSvEsabGi4VFN@PpiPJLwtX5KjsUqapfyPpB1qv7K/WSnXCcslJp2HaQDp1Ft5kuOBm3kQ6UXUiXnIzwy1mn5tZng/D8csPOxWgxN6eRZxJCC5dj4aQQ2UGlGoQ12zoXWrOFstK0hmcxyizqzKoQxuAf)

Ungolfed:

```python
n,m=x+w-1,y+h-1
r=[*map(list,a)]
for i in range(x,x+w):
 for j in range(y,y+h):
  p=u.index(a[j][i])
  c=(p%3,p%9//3,p%27//9,p//27)
  A,B=j in(y,m),i in(x,n)
  P=(i<n*A,y<j*B,x<i*A,j<m*B)
  l=sum(max(P[o]*t,c[o])*3**o for o in range(4))
  r[j][i]=u[l]
```

Comment: `(p%3,p%9//3,p%27//9,p//27)[o]` → `p//3**o%3` saves a bunch of bytes. Then `max(…)*3**o for` → `3**o*max(…)for` saves one more. And then you can eke one more out by inlining the `3**` and shuffling `P` around to index it with `o%5-1`, yielding: `sum(o*max((i<n*A,j<m*B,y<j*B,x<i*A)[o%5-1]*t,p//o%3)for o in(1,3,9,27))`

Comment: Err, that last step is a bad idea. Instead you can do `R=range` and get it down to [201](https://goo.gl/jKYyK6)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 174 bytes

```
r=a.map((l,j)=>l.map((c,i)=>u[c=u.indexOf(c),g=n=>c/n%3<t&&g(n,c+=n),j==y|j==h&&(i>=x&i<w&&g(1),i>x&i<=w&&g(9)),i==x|i==w&&(j>=y&j<h&&g(27),j>y&j<=h&&g(3)),c]),w+=x-1,h+=y-1)
```

```js
a=`
┏┱─────┐         ┌┐     ┎──┲━┓
┠╂─────┘         ││     ┃  ┗━┛
┃┃               ││     ┃     
┠╂──┲━━┓  ┏━━━━┓ ││    ┌╂┰┐   
┃┃  ┗━━┩  ┃    ┃ └╆━┓  └╂┸┘   
┃┃     │  ┃    ┃  ┃ ┃   ┃     
┗┹─────┘  ┗━━━━┛  ┗━┛   ╹     
`.match(/.+/g).map(s=>[...s]);
x=4;
y=1;
w=24;
h=4;
t=1;
u=" ╶╺╵└┕╹┖┗╴─╼┘┴┶┚┸┺╸╾━┙┵┷┛┹┻╷┌┍│├┝╿┞┡┐┬┮┤┼┾┦╀╄┑┭┯┥┽┿┩╃╇╻┎┏╽┟┢┃┠┣┒┰┲┧╁╆┨╂╊┓┱┳┪╅╈┫╉╋";
r=a.map((l,j)=>l.map((c,i)=>u[c=u.indexOf(c),g=n=>c/n%3<t&&g(n,c+=n),j==y|j==h&&(i>=x&i<w&&g(1),i>x&i<=w&&g(9)),i==x|i==w&&(j>=y&j<h&&g(27),j>y&j<=h&&g(3)),c]),w+=x-1,h+=y-1)
;document.write(`<pre style="font-family:Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif">${r.map(s=>s.join``).join`\n`}</pre>`);
```